# combine multiple filters with Or condition and send it Simple Odata Client - C#

Tags: c#, filter, conditional-statements, odata

I am trying to create filters in a loop that needs to be combined using OR condition to send to Simple OData Client as part of URL. This code joins it using AND condition and I need OR :

foreach (var note in noteFilters)

```
        {
            request = request.Filter(r => r.Notes.Any(n => n.Header == note.Header && n.Value == note.Note));

        }
```

I tried this code :

Expression>
  condition1 = r => r.Notes.Any(n => n.Header == noteFilters[0].Header && n.Value == noteFilters[0].Note);

```
            var filter = new ODataExpression(condition1);

            for (int i = 1; i <= noteFilters?.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Expression<Predicate<LocationWithNotesResponse>> condition2 = r => r.Notes.Any(n => n.Header == noteFilters[i].Header && n.Value == noteFilters[i].Note);

                filter = filter || new ODataExpression(condition2);
            }

            request = request.Filter(filter);
```

It gives me this error while converting condition1 to ODataExpression : Not supported expression of type System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression (MemberAccess): value(ServiceChannel.Api.ServiceChannelApiClient+<>c__DisplayClass12_0).noteFilters.get_Item(0).Header

My noteFilters can have one set of values (header and value) or multiple. That's why tries to create one filter initially and then rest of filters in loop to join with OR condition. If anyone has better idea to avoid this, I am happy to add. But most important to solve is to get the OR condition in filter.

Any Ideas would be a great help!

Comment: Here is an example how to create the in operator: https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/issues/576

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `&&` to `||`

```
request = request.Filter(r => r.Notes.Any(n => n.Header == note.Header || n.Value == note.Note));
```

You can find more about boolean logical operators [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-).

Comment: No, I want OR condition between each "note" that is looped through. Currently it is giving like